# Is there a way to package my r script into an android app?

Tags: android, r

I have an R program and I need to know if it is possible to package that into an android app. The R script uses an API and it currently stores results in a MongoDB. I want to display them on the app instead of storing them in a DB. Any ideas are welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's interesting.  I don't think it is possible to do it as you described.  Do you have Visual Studio?  If not, you can get it for free and you can use that to create apps that run on the Android OS.

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/android/

See these links as well.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/making-guis-using-c-and-r-with-the-help-of-r-net/

http://vvella.blogspot.com/2010/08/integrate-c-net-and-r-taking-best-of.html

https://www.codeproject.com/kb/cs/rtocsharp.aspx

If your script is not too complex, you can probably convert it to C# and you'll be in business then!